# Get the list of all Tables, Views, Stored procedures that are not added in a publication for replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

How do I get the list of all Tables, Views, Stored procedures that are NOT added  in a publication for replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Snapshot and Transactional:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM sysobjects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((xtype = 'U') OR (xtype = 'V') OR (xtype = 'P')) AND 
    category <> 2 AND 
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysarticles)
```

For Merge:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM sysobjects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((xtype = 'U') OR (xtype = 'V') OR (xtype = 'P')) AND 
    category <> 2 AND 
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysmergearticles)
```

Answer (score 2):

With added schema to Brandon's answer.

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS db, SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS [Schema], so.name, so.type
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN sysobjects so WITH(NOLOCK)
ON so.id=o.object_id
WHERE ((so.xtype = 'U') OR (so.xtype = 'V') OR (so.xtype = 'P')) 
AND so.category <> 2 
AND so.name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysarticles)
ORDER BY  so.name, so.type
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the entire information about Tables and stored Procedures and views

Check this link:

http://codedada.com/how-to-get-entire-information-about-sqlserver-database/